# how to fetch out the index/key from an array using its value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

how to fetch out the index/key from an array using its value  in PHP?

If i have an array say :

```
array{
        0 => 'Me',
        1 => 'You',
        2 => 'We'
}
```

then here how to find that value "**You**" has key "**1**"? Using any php logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) does the job I think

Comment: If you add a link to the documentation, I'll give you +1 ;)

Comment: If you add a canonical link to the documentation, I'll give you +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array =array{
    0 => 'Me',
    1 => 'You',
    2 => 'We'
}
$searchValue = "YOU"; 
$keys = array_keys($array, $searchValue); 

#test it 
print_r($keys);
```

this would work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$b = get_array_index($a, "YOU"); 
echo $b; //  print '1'
```

Comment: yup i know, i forgot to write my UD function for that.